# How to select all elements in Xml document with specific inner fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have xml:

```
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Name>BMW</Name>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Name>Mercedes</Name>
        <Color>Yellow</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Name>Mercedes</Name>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

And I need to choose all cars with color Blue. Is there a way I can do it efficiently with selectors or/and loops?

Comment: Please attach the code you tried in your question.

Comment: Have you thought of using [tag:xpath]?

Comment: @AmirrezaNoori I decided to edit text itself - removed "I know how".

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: @AmirrezaNoori Yes. I accepted the answer, it is what need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:contains()` selector and `parent` function of jQuery help for this goal.

The `:contains()` selector, selects all elements that contain the specified text. More information: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#contains1

The `.parent()` method, gets the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector. More information: https://api.jquery.com/parent/#parent-selector

In the following code `objs` contains two elements:

```js
var objs = $('Car>Color:contains("Blue")').parent()
console.log(objs.eq(0).html())
console.log(objs.eq(1).html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Name>BMW</Name>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Name>Mercedes</Name>
        <Color>Yellow</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Name>Mercedes</Name>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```